# Get LatLng from Polyline click in Android

Tags: android, maps, polyline

On Android, I have a map with a polyline on it. When I click on the map portion, onMapClick returns a LatLng. When I click on the polyline, onMapClick never fires, and if I register onPolylineClick, all it returns is the polyline itself.

How do I get the LatLng of the location clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Doh! The polyline was still "setClickable(true)". If the polyline is *not* clickable, the LatLng is returned in onMapClick.